# C Programming: I want to make my stopwatch continuous but when a key is pressed it seems to only go in a one second increment and stop

Tags: c

So my code performs stopwatch features. When I press the key <kbd>D</kbd> or <kbd>U</kbd> I want the stop watch to go up in count or down in count. It does this but it only does it for one second and stops. How would I make it continuous. i.e. i press the down key and they stopwatch counts down. Also how would I incorporate a reset key.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    char c;
    int time_elapsed = 0;
    int flag = 0;

    for (;;) {
        if (flag == 0) {
            Sleep(1000);
            time_elapsed++;
            printf("Time elapsed since stopwatch started = %d seconds\n",
                   time_elapsed);
        }
        if (kbhit()) {
            c = getch();

            if (c == 's') {
                /* Stop */
                printf("You pressed s, so stopwatch is being stopped!\n");
                flag = 1;
            } else if (c == 'u' && flag == 1) {
                /* Up */
                time_elapsed = time_elapsed + 1;
                printf("You pressed u, so stopwatch reading is increased by 1 second!\n");
                printf("Time elapsed since stopwatch started = %d seconds\n",
                       time_elapsed);
            } else if (c == 'd' && flag == 1) {
                 /* Down */
                time_elapsed = time_elapsed - 1;
                printf("You pressed d, so stopwatch reading is decreased by 1 second!\n");
                printf("Time elapsed since stopwatch started = %d seconds\n",
                       time_elapsed);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As a side comment, all of us will be able to help you better if you'd submit properly indented code.  This is very hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

You need a variable to store the direction the stopwatch is going and after `Sleep` you need to adjust `time_elapsed` based on the value of that variable.

Comment: If I changed the up down and stop if else statements to while loops could that work?

Comment: I wouldn't do that. Just use the `flag` to store the direction the stopwatch is going. On `u` and `d` keys, change the `flag` value. Get rid of the `if (flag==0)` and change `time_elapsed` on each loop based on the value of `flag`.

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit that I'm not completely sure what you are asking about. Am I correct in assuming that you want your program to stop counting when you press 's' and continue counting when you press 'u' or 'd'?

If this is the case, then your code doesn't work because you stay in state 1 after you pressed 'd' or 'u'. But counting only occurs in state 0, which counts up. So to count up, you have to switch back to state 0. To count down, you have to create another state and count down in that state.

**EDIT:**
Here is a working example that does what you want:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum {STOPPED, COUNTING_UP, COUNTING_DOWN} state;

int main()
{
    /* declare variables */
    state my_state;
    time_t time1, time2;
    char c;
    double time_difference, time_elapsed;

    /* initialize variables */
    time_elapsed = 0;
    my_state = STOPPED;

    /* show info */
    printf("Press 'u' to start counting up or 'd' to start counting down.\nPress 'q' to end program.\n\n");

    while(1)
    {
        c = getchar();
        time1 = time2;
        time2 = time(0);

        if (c == 'u' && my_state == STOPPED) {
            my_state = COUNTING_UP;
            printf("Started counting up.\n");
        }
        else if (c == 'd' && my_state == STOPPED) {
            my_state = COUNTING_DOWN;
            printf("Started counting down.\n");
        }
        else if (c == 's' && my_state == COUNTING_UP) {
            my_state = STOPPED;
            time_difference = difftime(time2, time1);
            time_elapsed += time_difference;
            printf("Stopped counting up. Counted up for %.0f seconds.\n", time_difference);
        }
        else if (c == 's' && my_state == COUNTING_DOWN) {
            my_state = STOPPED;
            time_difference = difftime(time2, time1);
            time_elapsed -= time_difference;
            printf("Stopped counting down. Counted down for %.0f seconds.\n", time_difference);
        }
        else if (c == 'q') {
            printf("Program is closing.\n");
            break;
        }
        else {
            continue;
        }

        /* show info */
        printf("Total count: %.0f seconds\n", time_elapsed);
        if (my_state == STOPPED) {
            printf("Press 'u' to start counting up or 'd' to start counting down.\nPress 'q' to end program.\n\n");
        }
        else if (my_state == COUNTING_UP) {
            printf("Press 's' to stop counting up.\nPress 'q' to end program.\n\n");
        }
        else if (my_state == COUNTING_DOWN) {
            printf("Press 's' to stop counting down.\nPress 'q' to end program.\n\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do I change states..?

Comment: I improved my answer and added working code. I hope it becomes clearer now.

Comment: This was an amazing amount of help. If I wanted to display the count of the stopwatch as it was counting up or down, how would I go about that?